# Textfield inside the scrollView iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am new to iPhone, I have 10 textfields in my application which are in a scrollview.
What i need is when user touches on a textfield,scrollview should scroll in such a way, so that  textfield should not be behind the keyboard.

Help me.

Thanks for your kind help to me.

Comment: **1.** move up the current view to the visible zone **2.** or reduce the `UIScrollView` size for the visible room when the keyboard shows.

Answer (score 1):

override the textfield delegate methods like this

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField]; 
}
```

//This method moves the current selected text field to the visible zone

```
-(void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView 
{ 
    CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y; 
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; 

    CGFloat availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 200; // Remove area covered by keyboard  

    CGFloat y = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0; 
    if (y < 0) { 
        y = 0; 
    } 
    [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES]; 
}
```

And when you want to dismiss the keyboard override this delegate

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self.scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```